# toogle input on load in varticial panel issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am making a application layout.
my vertical panel loads in expanded format i want to load as collapsed vertical panel like-

here is my codepen link for code -[https://codepen.io/anuj53214/pen/abNRrGO](http://codepen)

vertical menu should look like this on load
(i tried with on load jquery event that is written in on click but this worked like first expand then collapse on page laod)
[image]

Comment: OK and what have you tried? There's no code posted in the question, and it currently reads like you're giving us a task.

Comment: @Mitya tried ```$(".rad-sidebar").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
    $(".rad-body-wrapper").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");``` on load this is the event currently works on click

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get your result it is enough to trigger the click event at the end of its definition:

```
$(".rad-toggle-btn").on('click', function() {
      $(".rad-sidebar").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
      $(".rad-body-wrapper").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
}).trigger('click');
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

```js
$(".rad-toggle-btn").on('click', function() {
    $(".rad-sidebar").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
    $(".rad-body-wrapper").toggleClass("rad-nav-min");
}).trigger('click');
```

```css
*{box-sizing:border-box}body{background:#f3f3f4;line-height:normal;font-size:16px;font-family:sans-serif}body::-webkit-scrollbar-track{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);border-radius:10px;background-color:#f5f5f5}body::-webkit-scrollbar{width:10px;background-color:#407396}body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{border-radius:10px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);background-color:#407396}a{text-decoration:none}a:hover{text-decoration:none}.rad-navigation{position:fixed;left:0;right:0;top:0;height:50px;box-shadow:0 0 9px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1),0 -5px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.1);background:#fff;z-index:10000}.links{margin-right:30px;position:relative}.links li{list-style:none;position:relative;margin:10px;display:inline-block}.rad-dropmenu-item.active{display:block;-webkit-animation:flipInX .3s ease}.rad-logo-container{width:225px;text-align:center;height:50px;float:left;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}.rad-top-nav-container{float:right;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}.rad-logo,.rad-toggle-btn{text-decoration:none;position:relative;height:50px;line-height:50px;padding:0 15px;font-size:22px;font-weight:900;text-transform:uppercase;text-decoration:none;color:#222533;display:inline-block}.rad-toggle-btn:hover{background:#9494b8}.rad-menu-item{position:relative;padding:0 10px;line-height:30px;height:30px;color:#89949b;z-index:5}.rad-menu-badge{position:absolute;min-width:20px;min-height:20px;line-height:20px;font-weight:700;color:#fff;border-radius:100%;font-size:12px;background:#e94b3b;box-shadow:.5px .2px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);display:inline-block;text-align:center;top:-10px;z-index:1}.rad-dropmenu-item{position:absolute;right:0;top:40px;min-width:250px;background:#fff;border-top:5px solid #2f4050;border-radius:2px;box-shadow:0 0 5px rgba(0,0,0,.15);display:none}.rad-dropmenu-item:before{content:"";position:absolute;border-width:0 10px 10px 10px;border-style:solid;border-color:#2f4050 transparent;top:-14px;right:8px}.rad-dropmenu-footer,.rad-dropmenu-header{display:block!important;background:#f9fafb;text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:700;font-size:12px;margin:0!important;padding:6px;text-align:center}.rad-dropmenu-footer>a{color:#98a0a3;line-height:12px;text-decoration:none}.rad-dropmenu-header{border-bottom:1px solid #f2f2f2}.rad-dropmenu-header>a{color:#98a0a3;line-height:12px;text-decoration:none}.rad-dropmenu-footer{border-top:1px solid #f2f2f2}.rad-sidebar{z-index:9999;position:fixed;background:#2f4050;width:225px;height:100vh;top:50px;left:0;box-shadow:0 0 4px rgba(0,0,0,.14),2px 4px 8px rgba(0,0,0,.28);-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}.rad-sidebar li{text-align:left;height:50px}.rad-sidebar li a{text-decoration:none;height:50px;display:block;color:#fff}.rad-sidebar li a i{position:relative;width:50px;height:50px;line-height:50px;text-align:center}.rad-sidebar li a i:before{z-index:10;position:relative}.rad-sidebar li a>span{display:inline-block;padding-left:10px;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}.rad-sidebar li:hover{background:#263340}.rad-sidebar li:hover .icon-bg{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}.icon-bg{position:absolute;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;z-index:1;width:100%;-webkit-transform:translate3d(-47px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-47px,0,0);-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}.rad-bg-primary{background:#1c7ebb}.rad-bg-success{background:#23ae89}.rad-bg-danger{background:#e94b3b}.rad-bg-warning{background:#f98e33}.rad-bg-violet{background:#6a55c2}.rad-sidebar.rad-nav-min{width:50px!important}.rad-sidebar.rad-nav-min .rad-sidebar-item{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-200px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-200px,0,0)}.rad-sidebar.rad-nav-min .icon-bg{-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}.rad-sidebar.rad-nav-min .icon-bg:hover{opacity:.4}.rad-body-wrapper{position:absolute;left:250px;top:75px;width:auto;right:0;-webkit-transition:all .2s ease-in-out;transition:all .2s ease-in-out}.rad-body-wrapper.rad-nav-min{left:50px}.rad-chart{height:250px}@-webkit-keyframes flipInX{0%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,90deg);-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in;transition-timing-function:ease-in;opacity:0}40%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-20deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-20deg);-webkit-transition-timing-function:ease-in;transition-timing-function:ease-in}60%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,10deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,10deg);opacity:1}80%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-5deg);transform:perspective(400px) rotate3d(1,0,0,-5deg)}100%{-webkit-transform:perspective(400px);transform:perspective(400px)}}@media screen and (max-width:850px){.rad-navigation{height:100px}.rad-logo-container{display:block;float:none;width:100%;border-bottom:1px solid #f2f2f2}.rad-top-nav-container{display:block;float:none;height:50px;font-size:12px;background:#fff}.rad-menu-badge{font-size:10px;min-width:15px;min-height:15px;line-height:15px}.links{float:right}.rad-sidebar{top:100px}.rad-sidebar.rad-nav-min{-webkit-transform:translate3d(-200px,0,0);transform:translate3d(-200px,0,0)}.rad-body-wrapper{top:125px;position:relative}.rad-body-wrapper.rad-nav-min{left:0}}.panel{box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.26);border-radius:0!important}.panel-heading{background:#2f4050!important;border-radius:0;padding:15px;box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.26)}.panel-heading .panel-title{text-transform:uppercase;font-weight:600;font-size:12px;color:#dce0f3}#areaChart path[AttributesStyle]{fill:#39c7aa;stroke:none;fill-opacity:1}.menu{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;-webkit-box-direction:normal;flex-flow:row wrap;justify-content:space-around;max-width:700px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.menu a{color:#fff;margin:10px;padding:20px;text-align:center;font-size:14px;text-decoration:none;box-shadow:0 2px 5px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.26);border-radius:0!important;background-color:#2f4050!important;-webkit-transition:all ease-in-out 350ms;transition:all ease-in-out 350ms}.menu a:hover{color:#9ab9ce;background-color:#4b667f!important}.overlay{height:0%;width:100%;position:fixed;z-index:1;top:0;left:0;background-color:#000;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.99);overflow-y:scroll;-webkit-transition:.5s;transition:.5s}.overlay::-webkit-scrollbar-track{-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);border-radius:10px;background-color:#f5f5f5}.overlay::-webkit-scrollbar{width:10px;background-color:#407396}.overlay::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{border-radius:10px;-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);background-color:#407396}.overlay-content{position:relative;top:25%;width:100%;text-align:center;margin-top:30px}.overlay a{padding:8px;text-decoration:none;font-size:36px;color:#818181;display:block;-webkit-transition:.3s;transition:.3s}.overlay a:focus,.overlay a:hover{color:#f1f1f1}.overlay .closebtn{position:absolute;top:100px;right:45px;font-size:60px}.overlay-c{max-width:300px;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto}.field-container{-webkit-box-flex:1;flex:1 100%;margin-bottom:20px;margin-top:-1px;border-width:0 0 1px 0;border-style:solid;border-color:#407396}.field-container .input{width:100%;margin:0;padding:0 6px;border:none;outline:0;background:0 0;color:#fff}.field-container .text-area{min-height:38px;height:50px;margin:2px 0 3px;overflow-y:scroll;resize:none;-webkit-transition:height .1s;transition:height .1s}.field-container :-moz-placeholder,.field-container :-ms-placeholder,.field-container ::-webkit-input-placeholder{color:#407396}.button-container{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;margin:10px}.button-container a:hover{color:#fff}.button-container a{color:#407396;margin:5px;margin-right:40px;font-size:20px;text-decoration:none;-webkit-transition:all ease-in-out 350ms;transition:all ease-in-out 350ms}p{display:-webkit-box;display:flex;-webkit-box-pack:center;justify-content:center;color:#fff;font-size:40px;padding-bottom:50px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/morris.js/0.5.1/morris.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
<section>
    <header>
        <nav class="rad-navigation">
            <div class="rad-logo-container"><a class="rad-logo" href="#">p.m.s</a><a class="rad-toggle-btn pull-right" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></a></div>
            <div class="rad-top-nav-container">
                <ul class="links">
                    <li><a class="rad-menu-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-comment-o"> </i></a></li>
                    <li class="rad-dropdown"><a class="rad-menu-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o"><span class="rad-menu-badge">3</span></i></a>
                        <ul class="rad-dropmenu-item">
                            <li class="rad-dropmenu-header"><a href="#">Your Notifications</a></li>
                            <li class="rad-notification-item"><a class="rad-notification-content" href="#"></a></li>
                            <li class="rad-dropmenu-footer"><a href="#">See all notifications</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="rad-dropdown"><a class="rad-menu-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-bell-o"><span class="rad-menu-badge">49</span></i></a>
                        <ul class="rad-dropmenu-item">
                            <li class="rad-dropmenu-header"><a href="#">Your Alerts</a></li>
                            <li class="rad-notification-item"><a class="rad-notification-content" href="#"></a></li>
                            <li class="rad-dropmenu-footer"><a href="#">See all alerts</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a class="rad-menu-item" href="#"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"> </i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
</section>
<aside>
    <nav class="rad-sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="inbox" href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"><span class="icon-bg rad-bg-success"></span></i><span class="rad-sidebar-item">Dashboard</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-wrench"><span class="icon-bg rad-bg-violet"></span></i><span class="rad-sidebar-item">Settings</span></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</aside>
<main>
    <section>
        <div class="rad-body-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="menu"><a href="#" onclick="openaddteam()">ADD TEAM MEMBER</a><a href="#" onclick="opencreate()">CREATE PROJECT</a><a href="#" onclick="openset()">SET TASK</a></div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">team members</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">projects</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">event notification</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">project task progress</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="rad-chart" id="areaChart"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- here-->
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">number of project</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="rad-chart" id="donutChart"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div class="panel panel-default">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h3 class="panel-title">project stage</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                <div class="rad-chart" id="barChart"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</main>
```

Comment: i tried this solution issue is this code loads page in expanded vertical page then collapse, look weird